# Erlang Bit Syntax pattern matching works in shell but not as passed argument

Tags: parsing, syntax, erlang, udp, bit

I am trying to make a simple UDP packet decoder.

```
packet_decoder(Packet)->
<<Opts:8,MobIdLength:8,MobId:64,MobIdType:8,MgeType:8,SeqNum:16,Rest/binary>> = Packet,
io:format("Options:~p~n",Opts),
io:format("MobIdLength:~p~n",MobIdLength),
io:format("MobId:~p~n",MobId),
io:format("MobIdType:~p~n",MobIdType),
io:format("MgeType:~p~n",MgeType),
io:format("SeqNum:~p~n",SeqNum).
```

Packet is passed by a receive loop:

```
rcv_loop(Socket) ->
inet:setopts(Socket, [{active, once}, binary]),
io:format("rcvr started:~n"),
receive
    {udp, Socket, Host, Port, Bin} ->
        packet_decoder(Bin),
        rcv_loop(Socket)
end.
```

I keep getting(following error edited 9/7/12 9:30 EST):

```
** exception error: no match of right hand side value 
                    <<131,8,53,134,150,4,149,0,80,15,1,2,1,2,0,16,80,71,115,
                      52,80,71,115,53,24,63,227,197,211,...>>
     in function  udp_server:packet_decoder/1
        called as udp_server:packet_decoder(<<131,8,53,134,150,4,149,0,80,15,
                                              1,2,1,2,0,16,80,71,115,52,80,71,
                                              115,53,24,63,227,197,...>>)
     in call from udp_server:rcv_loop/1 
     in call from udp_server:init/0
```

If I create the same variable in the Erlang shell as a binary, i.e.

```
Packet = <<131,8,53,134,150,4,149,0,80,15,1,2,1,2,0,16,80,71,115,52,80,71,115,53,24,63,227,197,211,228,89,72,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,16,0,5,5,32,1,4,255,159,15,18,28,0,34,62,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,47,67>>.

<<Opts:8,MobIdLength:8,MobId:64,MobIdType:8,MgeType:8,SeqNum:16,Rest/binary>> = Packet.
```

It works just fine.  Is there some subtlety in passing this to a function that I am missing?  I have tried what I think is everything(except the right way).  I tried setting the type and size.  I also just tried

```
<<Rest/binary>> = Packet.
```

To no avail.  Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Thought I'm not sure, I guess the error means you cannot assign a value to a variable a second time.

Comment: Is this actual variant of your code? I ask cause this variant will never work (`io:format` accepts only `list` as a second argument). I know that this will not help you to fix main problem, but placing real piece of code will be more informative.

Comment: Ah you're right Alexey. It compiled just fine but the code never got there.  I changed it so when it does(hopefully) it actually prints something. It's strange the compiler doesn't throw an error or even a warning.

Comment: halfelf, all of the variables are unbound.  I tried changing them in case I am using some reserved words.

Comment: Completely irrelevant to this discussion is that setting `active` to `once` means that only the first packet will be received as a message. You either have to reset `active` to `once` after every message or use `gen_udp:recv` for the subsequent packets.

Comment: rvirding, it should do that when it calls itself `rcv_loop(Socket)` at the end of the receive block.  Am I missing something?  If I take out the packet_decode call it definitely works fine.

Comment: @tktak Yes, sorry, you're right I missed that.

Comment: @tktak I would do one small test and that is to print out `Packet` in `packet_decoder/1` **before** doing the match so you see what you are actually matching against. That would be the only reason I can see why it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out(kinda).  I had been working on this in erlide in eclipse which had worked fine for all of the other parts of the.  I tried compiling it from the erl shell and it worked fine. There must be some minor difference in the way eclipse is representing the source or the way it invokes the erlang compiler and shell.  I will take it up with erlide.org. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

The error you are getting when you run your code does not match your code. The error you are getting:

```
** exception error: no match of right hand side value ...
```

is a `badmatch` error and comes from an explicit `=` match where the pattern does not match the value from the RHS. There is no `=` in the code for `rcv_loop/1`. This implies that the loop you are running is not this code. So there are some questions to be asked:

- When you have recompiled the module containing `rcv_loop/1` have you restarted the loop so you run the new code? This is not done automagically.
- Are you sure you are loading/running the code you think you are? I know this question sounds stupid but it is very easy, and not uncommon, to work on one version of the code and load another. You need to get the paths right.

The other things about mentioned about your code would not give this error. The calls to `io:format/2` are wrong but would result in errors when you make the actual calls to `io:format/2`. Using the variable `Socket` as you do is not an error, it just means that you only want to receive UDP packets from just that socket.

Comment: The error is thrown at the second line in the first chunk of code(packet_decoder).  rcv_loop passes Bin to packet_decoder, where the attempted bit syntax pattern match occurs. in packet_decoder, the variable is Packet.

I've added some io:format/1 in there to test that this is the code being run.  I got tired of doing this in vim so I switched to erlide+eclipse.  I worried that I wasn't running the code I thought too.  I also fixed the io:format/2 to pass a list as the second attribute.  The code just never got there.

Comment: @tktak Ah, ok, that is not what the error message you showed indicates.

Comment: You're right.  Sorry I pasted that from a test I was doing.  I had tried to put the code in the rcv_loop to see if it had to do with the way I was passing it.  I will post the relevant error above.  Sorry for misleading.

Comment: @tktak My suggestion is print out `Packet` in `packet_decoder/1` before you try and match it to see what you actually are matching against. Otherwise everything looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT : the first part of my answer was completely wrong so in order to not mislead, I deleted it.**

Like spotted **Alexey Kachayev** io:format takes as second parameter a list, so :

```
packet_decoder(Packet)->
<<Opts:8,MobIdLength:8,MobId:64,MobIdType:8,MgeType:8,SeqNum:16,Rest/binary>> = Packet,
io:format("Options:~p~n",[Opts]),
io:format("MobIdLength:~p~n",[MobIdLength]),
io:format("MobId:~p~n",[MobId]),
io:format("MobIdType:~p~n",[MobIdType]),
io:format("MgeType:~p~n",[MgeType]),
io:format("SeqNum:~p~n",[SeqNum]).
```

Comment: in case of `rcv_loop( Socket ) -> ... receive {udp, Socket, Host, Port, Bin} -> ...` it will be pattern matching: only messages from `Socket` defined in function header would be received. So it's ok with this.